# dot net core System.Xml.XMLNode not found

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

what is equavalent for this code in dot net core :

```
Type[] typeArray1 = new Type[] { typeof(XmlNode), typeof(string) };
```

XMLNode not found in System.Xml assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I've added **System.Xml.XmlDocument** by Nuget Manager and works.

for more detail see [this](http://eliot-jones.com/2015/06/asp-vnext-system-xml).